# Where result in some columns are null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to reduce the amount of rows I insert in a table every day.

In about 5 to 10% of them, All I got is Primary Keys Values.
I'm wondering if there was any method to select only rows that got more than PK values.

For exemple, the result I got now :

```
PK1    PK2    cl1    cl2    cl3    cl4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
a      Louis  null   null   171    15
a      Jack   13     null   null   null
a      Marty  17     14     130    null
b      Louis  10     11     110    12
b      Jack   03     null   185    null
b      Marty  null   null   null   null
c      Louis  16     48     null   25
c      Jack   null   null   null   null
c      Marty  13     null   null   64
d      Louis  null   null   null   null
d      Jack   21     12     165    null
d      Marty  null   null   null   null
```

My desired result :

```
PK1    PK2    cl1    cl2    cl3    cl4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
a      Louis  null   null   171    15
a      Jack   13     null   null   null
a      Marty  17     14     130    null
b      Louis  10     11     110    12
b      Jack   03     null   185    null

c      Louis  16     48     null   25

c      Marty  13     null   null   64

d      Jack   21     12     165    null
```

Is there any request possible in SQL that can change to that ? For now I'm using this one below

```
SELECT 
    table.PK1,table.PK2,
    table.cl1,table.cl2,table.cl3,table.cl4,
FROM
    datatable table
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT : this is an exemple, there is more than a hundred column (not pk) and I don't want to filter with "where". (or just in worst case)

Comment: `WHERE COALESCE(cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4) IS [NOT] NULL`. If you need a solution for variable numbers of columns, that's trickier, but still doable with any dynamic SQL and `sys.columns`. If the issue is simply that your fingers get tired typing all those columns, use the script feature of SSMS (Script table as -> `SELECT` To -> New Query Editor Window). A solution where you really do not mention the other columns at all... I don't see that one. Maybe something with `*` and `CHECKSUM`, but I wouldn't trust such constructs as far as I could throw them.

Comment: If your table is very sparse, even when rows with all `NULL`s are eliminated, you may get some benefit out of [sparse columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns) and column sets. Note that this is a very niche feature (it was specifically included to support SharePoint, basically); you should check if it's of any use carefully. But in theory, a column set could be checked very efficiently for the presence of any values.

Comment: So what you need is, null value check against dynamic columns, right?

Comment: If you don't want to filter with where then you are out of luck.  The query is hard to read with no spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`coalesce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.  It takes any number of arguments and returns the first non-null argument.  So for example:

```
select coalesce(3, 1, 4);            -->  3
select coalesce(3, null, 4);         -->  3
select coalesce(null, 1, 4);         -->  1
select coalesce(null, null, 4);      -->  4
select coalesce(null, null, null);   -->  null
```

You can use this to check if all columns are `null`:

```
where coalesce(col1, col2, ..., colN) is null
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just to explicitly remove the rows where all are `NULL`:

```
where cl1 is not null or cl2 is not null or cl3 is not null . . .
```

There is not really a short-cut.  Although you can use `coalesce()`, that prevents the use of indexes on the query (but they weren't used anyway).

If you really want performance for this query, you can add a computed column:

```
alter table t add num_nulls as ( (case when col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) + (case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) + . . . );
```

Then you can add an index on `t(num_nulls)` and use this in a `where` clause.  For filtering out 5-10% of the rows, this is not effective.  But if you wanted to filter out 98%, then it would be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write columns names, you can do something like this.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @query = ISNULL(@query+', ','') + [name] 
                FROM  sys.columns 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourTableName') 
                AND  [name] != 'PK1' AND  [name] !=  'PK2';

SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM TmpTable WHERE COALESCE('+ @query +') IS NOT NULL';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

*A row will be ignored when all of the columns (cl1, cl2, cl3, cl4, ..., cln = null) values are null, except for the first two columns or for the columns you specified.(PK1, PK2)*

Output

[image: Output Result]